# Multiple desktops inside single screen

Tags: c++, qt

I need an information about user's created desktops, regardless one or more than one screen are connected to the machine.

Currently I have an application with tabs inside it, which can be detached and moved to another manually created desktop/s while main app remains on the 1st one (main) desktop. Can you suggest how to get the ids (and other available info) of desktops where detached tabs are located?

I've been searching how to get the number of user's created desktops using Qt framework, and QDesktopWidget class, but without success so far. QDesktopWidget class provides screen information, such as its total size, number of screens, geometry of each screen and so... but not info about virtual desktops created inside screen.

Answer (score 0):

These are not real desktops, these are "workpaces", they are specific to the desktop environment. So, as far as I can see, you've got two options:

- launch `wmctrl` utility with params via `QProcess` and get the output
- find wmctrl's [sources](https://github.com/dancor/wmctrl) and take some code from there (didn't try myself, but looks like `get_property()` & `list_desktops()` contain the desired)

In any case it's not gonna look like too portable solution, of course =)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am interested if there are some more ways to do that?